# SSIS Script Component Increment variable

Tags: c#, ssis, etl

I am trying to do what seems simple to me, but can't manage to implement it. I want to increment a simple variable in a Data flow Task...

The variable is set in the ReadWriteVariables, there is no output nor input columns.

This is the end-goal (I'll avoid sharing the monstrosity my current code is) :

```
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{
    public override void PostExecute()
    {
        base.PostExecute();

        Variables.intDatasourceUpdated++;
    }
}
```

I suppose I'm missing something (very junior with C# and .Net), so any help would be appreciated.

---

Edit:
I want to increment my "updated" or my "inserted" variables depending on the lookup : [lookup printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxKAx.png). Here, it is always "updated".

My error is : [error printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sddpa.png). Note that it says "at Variables.get_intDatasourceInserted()" but I never go to that branch here. So I commented the increment line in the "insert script" and it worked.

But then, when I'll have the "insert" case, as I currently have it deactivated, it won't increment.

Comment: What makes you think it isn't being incremented? Note that when your package stops executing, all variables go back to their default value - they are not preserved. There is quite likely an easier way to do what you are doing. If you are doing a lot of script inside SSIS, I suggest you're doing somehing wrong.

Comment: I always had an error (now that I think of it, I should have posted it too...). I'll edit my post with new findings.

Comment: Is all data on the same server? Don’t use SSIS use a stored procedure.

Comment: I can't do that: Company policy. Furthermore, this would be a nightmare to maintain.

Comment: IMHO it’s easier to maintain in a stored proc. It’s certainly faster. But I don’t know the full story. I’ve certainly seen my fair share of slow complicated SSIS packages full of script created by programmers that don’t know how to use databases!

Comment: We are in an undergoing process to redo the packages we had from 2008 to 2016, with a lot more experience, time, people and also a better mindset. And also, we don't have control over the procedures, only the DBAs do.

Comment: If you are using script components and lookups it wouldn’t appear that you’ve learnt too much. Anyway best of luck. Everyone has their own coding comfort zone (me included)

Comment: I just joined the team ;-) Only found a job in BI just now, after being a web-dev for a year and a half.

Comment: Welcome to BI :)

Comment: Thanks! I'm enthusiast :D

Answer (score 1):

"The collection of variables locked for read and write access is not available outside of PostExecute".

You are posting your "Update" snippet, the error is saying you are trying to update intDatasourceInserted which likely in your "Insert"s PreExecute().   Which isn't allowed.

In either case you'll still have an issue, since each task there execute simultaneously, waiting for pipeline data, and variables don't work well between tasks inside one data flow, you'll probably need to mangle the data itself as it flows or access the altered variable outside the data flow in the control flow.

Comment: Well, that's what I guessed, and also why I commented the line in the other script, on a hunch. But it makes little sense to me... I imagine it's linked to variable contexts or concurrency, or something like that?

The solution I found was to use a rowcount and another variable with an expression to add my rowcounts. It requires 20 variables...

For cleanliness's sake I'd like to redo it with the script component as I find it way better. I'll keep coming to this post in hope someone has the solution I want.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Context and concurrency is a good way to put it.   I set writable variables (and sometimes larger object variables) in data flow often and predictable only by not letting two task edit the same variable and with the sole intent to use it after the data flow is done in a downstream control task (any task after exiting the dataflow including other dataflows).

Answer (score 0):

Usually this can be done, by defining a new C# variable. Set the value of the SSIS-variable to the new variable and then back again.

```
// Declare user-defined variable and increase the value by 1
int variableValue = Convert.ToInt32(Dts.Variables["myVariable"].Value);

variableValue++;

// Write the new value back into the variable
Dts.Variables["myVariable"].Value = variableValue;
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to decalre the variable outside of row processing.

```
public int counter = 0;

public void main()
{
     counter++;
}
```

And at the end set the variable to counter.

post execute...

```
Variables.Counter = counter;
```